# Mathew 24:4-7 - consecutive according to grammar?

Tags: matthew, grammar

This is about only the meaning of the grammar in these verses.

In v9, the word `then` is used which unambiguously places the subsequent events after events in v4-7.

But in v4-7, there is no use of `then` separating the distinct events.

Does this mean there is no grammatical reason that each event in v4-7 is subsequent to the previous one?

“I went snorkeling, jet skiing, tanning” does not mean you first did those things in that order, nor does it mean every time you went tanning you first went jet skiing.

> Matt 24: **4** Jesus answered, “See to it that no one deceives you.
> **5** For many will come in My name, claiming, ‘I am the Christ,’ and will deceive many. **6** You will hear of wars and rumors of wars, but
> see to it that you are not alarmed. These things must happen, but the
> end is still to come. **7** Nation will rise against nation, and
> kingdom against kingdom. There will be famines and earthquakes in
> various places. **8** All these are the beginning of birth pains.

Answer (score 1):

There are essentially two matters here so let us take them separately.

**1. "Then" (V9)**

The adverb of time, "then" that begins V9 of Matt 24, is Τότε which can mean (as per the English "then") according to BDAG:

- 1a **at that time** of the past, Matt 2:17, 27:9, 16, Gal 4:8, 29, Heb 12:26, Matt 4:17, 16:21, 26:16, etc
- b **at that time** of the future, Matt 13:43, 1 Cor 13:12ab
- c **at that time** of anytime that fulfills certain conditions, 2 Cor 12:10
- 2 to introduce that which follows in time, **then, thereupon**, Matt 2:7, 4:1, 3:13, 15, 4:5, 10, 8:26, 12:22, 25:24-45, 26:65, Luke 11:26, 14:21, 21:10, etc.

So, what is the meaning here?  The context strongly suggests that it simply means, "at that time"; that is, all these things will occur after Christ leaves and before Jesus' return, which is repeated in V11.

**2. Simultaneous or Sequential?**

The text of Matt 24:4-14 provides a list, in no particular order, of the kinds of events that will occur before the great "abomination of desolation" (V15), namely:

- For many will come in My name, claiming, ‘I am the Christ,’ and will deceive many.
- You will hear of wars and rumors of wars, but see to it that you are not alarmed. These things must happen, but the end is still to come. Nation will rise against nation, and kingdom against kingdom.
- There will be famines and earthquakes in various places. All these are the beginning of birth pains.
- they will deliver you over to be persecuted and killed, and
- you will be hated by all nations because of My name.
- many will fall away and will betray and hate one another,
- many false prophets will arise and mislead many.
- Because of the multiplication of wickedness, the love of most will grow cold. But the one who perseveres to the end will be saved.
- And this gospel of the kingdom will be preached in all the world as a testimony to all nations, and then the end will come.

Subsequent history has proved the correctness of this understanding.  In the time following Jesus, all the above events have occurred repeatedly, in various places, etc.  For example, there have always been false prophets, always false christs, always wars, always earthquakes, always persecution of Christians, always betrayals, always Gospel preaching, always famines, etc, etc.

Thus, Jesus is simply saying that these things will occur and when we observe them we should be reminded of Jesus' prediction and His return.

Comment: Their order also matches the 6 seals

Comment: @Maximus1987 - there are some remarkable parallels between this sermon in Matt 24 and the seven seals.  However, that is another question.